# react putting DOM manipulations directly in ref callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div
      ref={(ref) => {
        // Use DOM Api here directly, something like
        // ref.querySelector('.someclass').thirdParty().init()
      }}
    >
      ...
    </div>
  }
}
```

In the code above, is it considered good practice to put DOM manipulation direct in that ref callbacks?

I am mainly worried about **performance**, as I am unsure how often is `ref` called internally by `React`.

Comparing to the following approach, (which is what I am using atm)

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Use DOM Api here, something like
    // this.someRef.querySelector('.someclass').thirdParty().init()
  }
  render() {
    <div
      ref={(ref) => this.someRef = ref}
    >
      ...
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this should be on a case-by-case basis. With React, refs are only required for stuff which you can't do using virtual-DOM. Its mostly for user agent effects (e.g. scrolling elements into view). Most of the performance critical use cases impact v-dom and React takes care of them. Other than that, ref is invoked by react whenever your component mounts and gets attached to its DOM element.